# Sample codes for PHP Webservice

Tags: php, web-services, sample

I am new to PHP,I need to create Webservices using  PHP.Can anybody provide me the sample coding and the procedure steps to proceed?

Thanks in Advance,
Meena

Comment: What kind of web services? Please specify the technology, I'm sure people will be able to point you into the right direction.

Comment: maybe you can elaborate your question more?? Are you using a framework? what specific webservice?? etc

Answer (score 0):

A good (but old) article here: http://oreilly.com/pub/a/php/2007/07/26/php-web-services.html

Also: http://php.net/manual/en/refs.webservice.php

Answer (score 0):

I found following links may be it is useful for you

http://www.sks.com.np/article/8/xml-web-service-using-php-and-soap.html

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41844/Webservice-Client-and-Server-demo-in-PHP